# Android studion error Okhttp3 not uploading audio file after clicking a button

Tags: android, mysql, audio-recording, okhttp

Hello yesterday i saw a tutorial using okhtpp3 when uploading a file to server (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K48jnbM8yS4) I follow the tutorial and it is working perfectly but now I am trying to develop an app which has a record button to record audio and save to internal storage and another button to upload the audio file.

But it is not uploading the file.

My app code:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


        private String n="";

        private Button mRecordBtn,uploadBtn;
        private TextView mRecordLabel;
        private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

        private String mFileName = null;
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "Record_log";

        final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE =1000;

        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            if(!checkPermissionFromDevice()){
                requestPermission();

            }

            mRecordLabel =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordLbl);
            mRecordBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);


            mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.3gp";



            mRecordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (checkPermissionFromDevice()) {




                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        startRecording();
                        mRecordLabel.setText("Recording Started...");

                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                        stopRecording();
                        mRecordLabel.setText("Recording Stoped...");
                    }

                }
                else{
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


                uploadBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.uplaodBtn);
                uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        sendFile();

                    }
                });


        }

        private void startRecording() {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }

            mRecorder.start();
        }

        private void stopRecording() {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;





        }

        private void requestPermission(){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            },REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch(requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }


                break;
            }


        }

        private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice(){

            int write_internal_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int record_audio_result =ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            int read_internal_storage_result =ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            return  write_internal_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && read_internal_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;


        }



        private void sendFile() {



            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            File f = new File(mFileName);
            String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());
            String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();

            RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("title", content_type)
                    .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://192.168.8.100/etrack/save_audio.php")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    //                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
    //                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    //                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                }
                }
            });
        }

    private String getMimeType(String path){

        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);


    }
}
```

And here is my php code:

```
    <?php

$file_path = "images/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$file_path)) {
    echo "success";
}else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

My Build:gradle code:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "www.teamruby.com.samplerecord"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
}
```

Comment: data.addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", "audio.wav", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("media/type"), new File(path)));

Comment: you have to upload audio as a file and also file type is missing try with my code it's working for me

Comment: hello sir Kamlesh where can i exactly put your code? and what is "audio.wav because I have a File f which has mfilename. mfilename is the path to saved file.3gp

Comment: it's just file name you can add anything like you have file.3gp you can add that one too.

Comment: RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/3gp"), new File(mFileName));


        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("title", content_type)
       .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", "file.3gp",file_body)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.8.100/etrack/save_audio.php")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

Comment: can you please add more info on whre i exactly put your code sir or maybe you can edit mine. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File f = new File(mFileName);
MultipartBody.Builder data = new MultipartBody.Builder();
                data.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
                data.addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", "file.3gp", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("media/type"), f));
                RequestBody requestBody = data.build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("192.168.8.100/etrack/save_audio.php").post(requestBody)
                        .build();
```

Comment: I tried your code and still not working maybe in some part of code has an error. I didn't change any codes in the backend

Comment: Above code is working fine for me just verify your code with mine.

Comment: okay i found the problem and the solution, the problem is I have no permission to save any file to that folder and the solution is by adding permission to folder to read and write.